# Elements in pdf overlap each other while working with itext7

Tags: java, itext7

I have created a pdf file which needs to be appended for each iteration in a loop. As appending needs a temp file and then replacing the original file with this code`

```
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(report), new PdfWriter(temp));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
    doc.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));

    Table table = new Table(3);
   
    table.addCell(new Paragraph("Test ID:"+testid));
    table.addCell(new Paragraph("Testname:"+testname));
    table.addCell(new Paragraph("Result:"+result));
    

    doc.setRenderer(new DocumentRenderer(doc) {
        protected LayoutArea updateCurrentArea(LayoutResult overflowResult) {
            LayoutArea area = super.updateCurrentArea(overflowResult);
            if (area.getPageNumber() == 1) {
                area.getBBox().decreaseHeight(266);
            }
            return area;
        }
    });

    doc.add(table);
    doc.add(new Paragraph("\n\n"));
    Style normal = new Style();
    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN);
    normal.setFont(font).setFontSize(9);
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
    paragraph.add(new Text("Description"+System.lineSeparator()+output ).addStyle(normal));
    
    paragraph.setBorder(new SolidBorder(1));
     doc.add(paragraph);
     
    doc.close();
    
    
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(temp);
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(report);
    
    PdfDocument pdfDocoment = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
    
    //manipulate pdf…
    pdfDocoment.close();
```

i get a pdf but all the elements just overlap eachother. So how to do it properly.
My current pdf

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question but you probably want to add the content to the new page at the end of the document on every big iteration.

You have the following code which was probably meant to achieve the goal:

```
doc.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
```

However, it will not jump to the last page because `Document` does not "see" if some content already exist on pages and it just starts from the top of the first page even if you modify an existing document.

The solution is to jump to the last page and then create a new page. This can easily be achieved with these two lines:

```
doc.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.LAST_PAGE));
doc.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
```

It will not remember positions of the added content and just create new pages each time. If you want to remember those positions you will need to write additional code and pass those positions to the `currentArea` as you did in your custom renderer.

By the way, setting up custom renderer must be done before adding page breaks so the order should be as follows:

```
doc.setRenderer(new DocumentRenderer(doc) {
    protected LayoutArea updateCurrentArea(LayoutResult overflowResult) {
        LayoutArea area = super.updateCurrentArea(overflowResult);
        if (area.getPageNumber() == 1) {
            area.getBBox().decreaseHeight(266);
        }
        return area;
    }
});

doc.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.LAST_PAGE));
doc.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
```